# Select different printer based on paper size automaticly

Tags: windows, printer

I have the following problem: 
I have got two printers (an A4 printer and an A3 printer)

I created 2 printers on the computer named very clearly A3 Printer and A4 Printer.

But apparently that's too hard for the users to understand and A4 papers are regularly sent to the A3 printer and vice versa.

Does anyone know a way to solve this? Is there a way to let Windows automatically decide which printer to select based on the paper size?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already researched and/or tried so far? What version of windows? These are network printers, correct?

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm not too sure about this but another question might be how is it supposed to know what size the paper is? What program will they be printing from?